# How to Return LINQ results and display in view?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, linq, group-by

I have something that kind of works, but not sure how to tie it all together so I can display in my view model.

I have a repository class named **QVRRepository.cs** which looks like this:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using VTracker.Contexts;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;

namespace VTracker.Repositories
{
    public class QVRRepository : IQVRRepository
    {

        // Declare variable to hold the QVRDataContext object to call using LINQ queries
        private QVRDataContext _context;
        private ILogger _logger;

        // Constructor class to call and assign data context on init
        public QVRRepository(QVRDataContext context, ILogger<QVRRepository> logger)
        {
            _context = context;
            _logger = logger;
        }

        public class VulnerabilityCount
        {
            public string Owner { get; set; }
            public List<KeyValuePair<string, int>> StatusCounts { get; set; }
        };

        public IEnumerable<VulnerabilityCount> GetCountsByStatus()
        {
            string owner;
            List<KeyValuePair<string, int>> statusCounts = new List<KeyValuePair<string, int>>();

            List<VulnerabilityCount> vulnerabilityCounts = new List<VulnerabilityCount>() { };

            var query =
                    from o in _context.QVRData
                    group o by o.RamOwnedBy into ownerGroup
                    orderby ownerGroup.Key
                    select ownerGroup;


            foreach (var group in query)
            {
                owner = group.Key;
                Console.WriteLine(owner);

                foreach (var o in group.GroupBy(o => o.AdditionalResourcesRequired))
                {

                    statusCounts.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, int>(o.Key, o.Count()));
                    Console.WriteLine($"\t{o.Key} : {o.Count()}");

                }

                vulnerabilityCounts.Add(new VulnerabilityCount()
                {
                    Owner = owner,
                    StatusCounts = statusCounts
                });
            }

            return vulnerabilityCounts;

        }
    }
}
```

The intention is to return something similar to the SQL query:

```
select [RAM Owned By], [Additional Resources Required], count([Additional Resources Required])
from QVRData
group by [RAM Owned By], [Additional Resources Required]
order by [RAM Owned By], [Additional Resources Required]
```

With the code from **QVRRepository.cs** I am writing to the Console the results and I am seeing the results displayed as I would like:

```
CBT-Platform Management-CCI
    Researching - RRO Team - App Team Is Not Product Owner : 447
    Blank : 4131
    Researching - App Team - Not Yet Scheduled : 5
    Compliant : 19
    Researching - RRO Team - No Solution Available : 11
CBT-Platform Management-EBS
    Researching - RRO Team - App Team Is Not Product Owner : 1045
    Blank : 7995
    Scheduled : 447
    Compliant : 32
    Researching - App Team - Not Yet Scheduled : 12
    Blocked : 1
    Researching - RRO Team - No Solution Available : 1
    Exception Required in Policyworks : 3
```

But I'm struggling to figure out how I can these results compiled as a group of object so that I can display them in my view in a similar way.

In my *Index.cshtml** I have the following:

```
@model IEnumerable<VTracker.Repositories.QVRRepository.VulnerabilityCount>

@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "QVR";
}

<div class="flex-container">
    @foreach (var i in Model)
    {
        <div class="qvr-card">
            <div class="qvr-card-header">
                <p class="text-center">@i.Owner.Replace("CBT-", "").Replace("Platform Management", "Platform-MGMT")</p>
            </div>
            <div class="inner-container">
                   <div>
                       @foreach (var s in i.StatusCounts)
                       {
                        <div>@s.Key</div>
                        <div>@s.Value</div>
                       }
                   </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    }
</div>
```

As you can see in my screenshot below, I've really got this properly screwed up...

The first foreach returns the owner values as the header fine, but instead of displaying the status counts for only the "owner", it's displaying all counts (status + counts) for all "owners" under each one:

[image]

Comment: Possibly not related, but `statusCounts` should be declared inside your outer `foreach`

Comment: put a breakpoint in your `cshtml` and check the loop

Comment: @StephenMuecke I've made some edits. Not sure if what I have uploaded now changes anything..

Comment: @adiga when I add breakpoint to the foreach loop in Index.cshtml I see that it's "i.StatusCounts" has 45 items (status.key, status.value). So that explains why each "owner" is displaying the statuses and counts for all owner groups. Any ideas on how I can limit so it only shows the status.key and status.value for just each individual owner?

Comment: Now your new image makes sense for the code you had :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your `GetCountsByStatus` method, you are initializing `statusCounts` outisde the `for` loop. So, every item in your `vulnerabilityCounts` collection has the same reference to `statusCounts`. Move it to inside your `for` loop:

```
foreach (var group in query)
{
    // there is no need to keep this outside either
    string owner = group.Key;

    // for every owner, the statusCounts gets initialized again
    List<KeyValuePair<string, int>> statusCounts = new List<KeyValuePair<string, int>>();
    Console.WriteLine(owner);

    foreach (var o in group.GroupBy(o => o.AdditionalResourcesRequired))
    {
        statusCounts.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, int>(o.Key, o.Count()));
        Console.WriteLine($"\t{o.Key} : {o.Count()}");
    }

    vulnerabilityCounts.Add(new VulnerabilityCount()
    {
        Owner = owner,
        StatusCounts = statusCounts
    });
}
```